# Writing an SQL Query for an ipl database

Tags: sql

Find, for each match venue, the average number of runs scored per match (total of both teams) in the stadium. You can get the runs scored from the ball_by_ball table. Output <venue_name, avg_runs> , in descending order of average runs per match.

Tables:

```
venue - venue_id,
        venue_name

match - match_id,
        team1,
        team2,
        venue_id

ball_by_ball - match_id,
               over_id,
               ball_id,
               runs_scored
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
select venue_name,
    (select sum(runs_scored)
     from venue
     inner join match on venue.venue_id = match.venue_id
     inner join ball_by_ball on match.match_id = ball_by_ball.match_id
     group by venue_name)
     /
     (select count(match_id)
      from venue
      inner join match on venue.venue_id = match.venue_id
      group by venue_name) as avg_runs 
from venue
```

I am getting an error

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I am new to SQL - please help me out

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Yeah sure. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the runs per match and then use average as follows:

```
Select venue_id, avg(run_per_match) as avg_run_per_venue from
(select match.match_id, venue.venue_id
       sum(runs_scored) run_per_match
     from venue
     inner join match on venue.venue_id = match.venue_id
     inner join ball_by_ball on match.match_id = ball_by_ball.match_id
     group by match.match_id, venue.venue_id) t
Group by venue_id
```